# How to bind to an element inside a control template from a resource dictionary outside of the template but in the same Window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, controltemplate, xaml-resources

The problem I am facing is a too big XAML file. I want to separate things into resources.

The `Header` of the MenuItem is rendered without text, and it is neither working with `x:Reference` and `Binding.Source` instead of `Binding.ElementName`.

If I give the `Header` property below a local value, it works. I need this context menu available in this resource dictionary because I use it in many other big resources (especially big `DataTemplate`s in the same resource dictionary.

If I put this `ContextMenu`, and all the resources using it from `Window.Resources` into `ControlTemplate.Resources`, everything works, but I would like to separate them for better organization because they are big.

I have searched Stack Overflow for duplicate questions but I did not find something similar to my situation. I thought about it for a while and I did not find a tehnique that helps me. (I have read only about 80% of Pro WPF 4.5.)

## XAML

*(there is no code-behind other than that autogenerated code)*

```xml
<Window x:Class="wpf_test_1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_test_1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock,
                                    Path=Text}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button>
            A button
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="Test"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Actual**: The context menu of the first/root `Grid` has a single `MenuItem` that has an empty `Header`. This can be checked by right clicking this `Grid`.

**Expected:** It should have the `Header` set to "Test".

## Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Thank you.

## Update 1

The ContextMenu in my actual project begins like this:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Click="ApplyFilters_Click"
        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyListView,
                    Path=SelectedItems.Count,
                    Converter={StaticResource MultipleSelectedToVisibleConv}}"
        Header="_Apply filters">
    </MenuItem>
```

## Update 2

`MyContextMenu` is shown when the user right-clicks any element in the `MyListView`. For MyListView I have 4 combinations of DataTemplates, GridView and ItemsPanelTemplate that offer the user 4 ways to view the information. Each DataTemplate references the MyContextMenu so it is shown when the user right-clicks an item.

## Update 3

I meant "right-clicks any item in MyListView".

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LargeIconsWithViewboxTemplate">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Tag="{Binding Path=MyFilter}"
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}"
                Width="84" Height="60" ToolTip="{Binding Path=DisplayString}">
[...]
```

Comment: I have added more details in the question. Thank you.

Comment: How is `MyListView` related to the `ContextMenu`? You can't use `ElementName` unless the element you are referring to resides in the same namescope.

Comment: I have added more information in the question. Thank you.

Comment: "Right-clicks any element"? So how do you set the `ContextMenu` property to `MyContextMenu` and on which element are you doing this?

Comment: I posted another update. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to get a reference to the `ListView` from the `ContextMenu` resource in the `ResourceDictionary` using pure XAML given this setup.